# how to write to a text file without overwriting?

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

I am in a deadlock as to how to write the attributes in a form to a text file in java. I know there are many answers to this but i couldn't find any solution to the problem that i am facing. While there are many attributes in a form when i try writing them to a file it gets overwritten.
Eg: there are 3 attributes
when i try writing them to a file the third one overwrites the second one.

Here's what i have done so far:

```
writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/example1.txt"),true);
if(specific attr found)
    writer.println("my data");
writer.flush();
if(another found)
    writer.println("my data");
writer.flush();
if(third attr found)
    writer.println("my data");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

but its not working.

Comment: Try getting rid of the flushing

Comment: Your example is valid and working. There must be something else you are not sharing with us.

Comment: You have set the printwriter autoflush flag to true, you should remove those flush statements.  Other than that its probably an issue with your if statement that cannot find the second attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileUtils CommonsIO 2.4 API

Example

```
package com.doc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("test.txt");
        FileUtils.write(file, "\n my data", true);
        FileUtils.write(file, "\n my data", true);
        FileUtils.write(file, "\n my data", true);

    }
}
```

output

```
 my data
 my data
 my data
```

Comment: Thanks everyone...Its working.after i removed my flush.. @pavel & @ farlan i did had problem with my if statement.Though it was a silly mistake on my part but anyways help is appreciated :)